# Admin Entry Missing Sidebar

Tags: entries, admin

I've run into an issue on the admin backend for my site. When opening an entry, the sidebar is missing. In addition, all the interactive elements (deleting a block, removing an asset, viewing the save dropdown, etc), do not work. I can still edit visible elements and click "Save," which works.

The debug toolbar also will not load on that page. However, the browser console shows no errors.

Outside of entries, the rest of the backend works fine.

I've tried these troubleshooting steps:

- Ensured Craft and all plugins are up to date
- Rebuilt the config
- Re-applied YAML changes
- Deleted and rebuilt the vendor folder
- Ensured queue manager is empty
- Cleared all caches
- Invalidated data caches

[image]

Comment: Do you have any browser extensions installed that block scripts? Can you reproduce this on multiple browsers?

Comment: Yes it does reproduce itself on different browsers. I got an update from Craft support that I'll post below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craft support was able to investigate and the issue was caused by unescaped HTML being used in the "Default Instructions" area of a field's settings.

So for example, if the Default Instructions for a field said something like "This field content is rendered inside a <p> tag," the entries that used that field would treat that `<p>` inside the instruction helper text as HTML.

The temporary solution is to escape it with backticks, so one would write: "This field content is rendered inside a `<p>` tag."

Craft also mentioned they would post an additional fix in an upcoming release.